# Selenium clicks an element sucesfully but actualy its not clicked. And this happens only during parllel execution. Otherwise its working fine

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am running my scenarios in parallel. In the same scenario, I am running parallel in 5 windows. The one which has focus is working as expected. The other ones are failing at click. It is trying to identify the next element without actually clicking the previous element. If I focus on each and every tab manually when that particular element is clicked it is working. Could you please help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you might not have your testng file setup correctly to run the parallel mode.

Are Five browsers launched at once ? When you look in each browser, is it waiting for driver to complete task on the first brower before it moves to the second browser ?

Post your testng.xml so people can have a look.

Also, best practise is to use threadlocal concept to save lot of other headaches when and if you run test on parallel mode

Answer (score 0):

Selenium works as expected only in the active(focused) window.As we know only one window/tab can be in active mode at once.So if you want to observe the same in another tab/window we need to switch the focus(using driver.switchTo().)